# drupal 7 view filter criteria value input

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a content type called Event, which has a date field. I created a new view for the content type and added filtering by date as filter criteria. If I enter inside filter configuration I can choose the operator and enter the value inside the input. What I need to do is to split this input into three sepparate inputs for day, month and year. I need to do this inside a custom module. I need to add the value from the admin interface but modify the input via code. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the form alter and change the format,

do this in custom module,

```
<?php
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
...
  if($form_id == 'views_exposed_form'){
    if($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-events-all-search-panel-pane-1'){
      $format = 'm-d-Y';
      $form['date_filter']['min']['#date_format'] = $format;
      $form['date_filter']['max']['#date_format'] = $format;
    }
...
}
```

OR you can try [Better exposed filter](https://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module.

Project page says:

> What's new?
>
> The 7.x release now includes support for the **jQuery UI Datepicker
>   instead of a textbox** for date-related fields. Since Drupal 7 ships
>   with jQuery UI in core, my hope is to start offering these as options
>   in BEF. If you have any suggestions, please add a feature request to
>   the issue queue.
>
> (Note: Support for fields supplied by the Date module is a little
>   funky until #392836: Exposed Date filter format (in Views) and/or
>   Date format in exposed filter (views) are resolved).

Comment: The module won't work because the filter I use is not exposed.